# Npgsql Enum Error

Tags: npgsql

I am getting the following error message when trying to persist an enumeration using Npgsql V3.05.

> Enums must be registered with Npgsql via Connection.RegisterEnumType or RegisterEnumTypeGlobally

I created a type in PostgreSQL in PostgrSQL, and verified it with following query:

```
select enum_range(null::schedule_link_type);
```

which returns

```
"{finish_to_start,finish_to_finish,start_to_start,start_to_finish}"
```

I created an enum in my VB.NET program as (note that this is in my `ActionRecord` class):

```
Public Enum ScheduleLinkType
    <EnumLabel("finish_to_start")>
    FinishToStart
    <EnumLabel("finish_to_finish")>
    FinishToFinish
    <EnumLabel("start_to_finish")>
    StartToFinish
    <EnumLabel("start_to_start")>
    StartToStart
End Enum
```

I call the following method before running the insert query (note that I set a breakpoint andconfirmed this is really being called before the insert command is executed):

```
NpgsqlConnection.RegisterEnumGlobally(Of ActionRecord.ScheduleLinkType)("schedule_link_type")
```

The parameter for field that I am trying to insert is (from the Visual Studio debugger watch window):

```
command.Parameters(1)   {Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter}    Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter
    Collection  {Npgsql.NpgsqlParameterCollection} Npgsql.NpgsqlParameterCollection
    DbType  Object {13} System.Data.DbType
    Direction   Input {1}   System.Data.ParameterDirection
    EnumType    {Name = "ScheduleLinkType" FullName = "VSData.ActionRecord+ScheduleLinkType"}   System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
    IsNullable  False   Boolean
    NpgsqlDbType    Enum {47}   NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType
    NpgsqlValue FinishToFinish {1}  Object {VSData.ActionRecord.ScheduleLinkType}
    ParameterName   "link_type" String
    Precision (System.Data.Common.DbParameter)  0   Byte
    Precision   0   Byte
    Scale (System.Data.Common.DbParameter)  0   Byte
    Scale   0   Byte
    Size    0   Integer
    SourceColumn    ""  String
    SourceColumnNullMapping False   Boolean
    SourceVersion   Current {512}   System.Data.DataRowVersion
    Value   FinishToFinish {1}  Object {VSData.ActionRecord.ScheduleLinkType}
```

Anybody know why this is not working?

Comment: It seems that if I register the Enum via Connection.RegisterEnumType it works, but if I register the Enum via NpgsqlConnection.RegisterEnumTypeGlobally it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has gone away for some reason, and everything works as expected now (note that I have updated NPGSQL to 3.1.8 since posting the original question, but I did not notice if this problem went away due to the upgrade or something else I changed).