# npgsql says enum is not registered

Tags: c#, postgresql, enums, npgsql

I'm trying to insert some data with enums via Npgsql. At first, everything worked fine, but I have noted, that some of my Enums don't work. I have mapped all my c# enums to the postgres enums but when trying to use them, some of them give me the following message:

> The CLR enum type One_More_Enum must be registered with Npgsql
>   before usage, please refer to the documentation

I think i have mapped my enums according to the documentation. At least the enums `Some_Enum` and `Another_Enum` work just fine.

Here is my code:

```
//Enum declaration
public enum Some_Enum
{
    [PgName("SOME_VALUE")]
    SOME_VALUE,
    [PgName("ANOTHER_VALUE")]
    ANOTHER_VALUE,
    [PgName("ONE_MORE_VALUE")]
    ONE_MORE_VALUE
}

public enum Other_Enum
{
    [PgName("SOME_VALUE")]
    SOME_VALUE,
    [PgName("ANOTHER_VALUE")]
    ANOTHER_VALUE,
    [PgName("ONE_MORE_VALUE")]
    ONE_MORE_VALUE
}

public enum One_More_Enum
{
    [PgName("SOME_VALUE")]
    SOME_VALUE,
    [PgName("ANOTHER_VALUE")]
    ANOTHER_VALUE,
    [PgName("ONE_MORE_VALUE")]
    ONE_MORE_VALUE
}

//Register my enums according to the documentation
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<Some_Enum>("some_enum");
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<Other_Enum>("other_enum");
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<One_More_Enum>("one_more_enum");

using (var connection = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
{
    connection.Open();

    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO TABLE_A (NAME, SOME_ENUM) VALUES (@NAME, @SOME_ENUM) RETURNING ID";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("NAME", "Foo Bar");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SOME_ENUM", Some_Enum.SOME_VALUE);
    var A_id = command.ExecuteScalar(); //Works fine...

    command.Parameters.Clear();

    command.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO TABLE_B (A_ID, NAME, FOO, BAR, OTHER_ENUM)" +
                        $"VALUES (@A_ID, @NAME, @FOO, @BAR, @OTHER_ENUM) RETURNING ID";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("NAME", "Some Name Bla Bla");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("A_ID", A_id);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FOO", false);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BAR", false);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("OTHER_ENUM", Other_Enum.ANOTHER_VALUE);
    var B_id = command.ExecuteScalar(); //Works fine

    command.Parameters.Clear();

    command.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO TABLE_C (B_ID, NAME, ONE_MORE_ENUM) VALUES (@B_ID, @NAME @ONE_MORE_ENUM) RETURNING ID";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("B_ID", B_id);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("NAME", "Hey Ho Name");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ONE_MORE_ENUM", One_More_Enum.ONE_MORE_VALUE);
    var D_id = command.ExecuteScalar(); //!!! Error is thrown here...
}
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065960/npgsql-enum-error) question here on stack, where the problem seemed to be solved by registering the enums not globally, but via connection (But the poster of the question doesn't think this solved his problem (look at his answere)). I have tried it like this:

```
//Register my enums according to the documentation
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<Some_Enum>("some_enum");
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<Other_Enum>("other_enum");
//NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<One_More_Enum>("one_more_enum");

using (var connection = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
{
    connection.Open();
    connection.TypeMapper.MapEnum<One_More_Enum>("one_more_enum");
    connection.ReloadTypes();

    //...
}
```

But I get the same error message...

---

Here is the declaration of the enums in postgre:

```
CREATE TYPE SOME_ENUM AS ENUM ('SOME_VALUE', 'ANOTHER_VALUE', 'ONE_MORE_VALUE');
ALTER TYPE SOME_ENUM OWNER TO postgres;
CREATE TYPE ANOTHER_ENUM AS ENUM ('SOME_VALUE', 'ANOTHER_VALUE', 'ONE_MORE_VALUE');
ALTER TYPE ANOTHER_ENUM OWNER TO postgres;
CREATE TYPE ONE_MORE_ENUM AS ENUM ('SOME_VALUE', 'ANOTHER_VALUE', 'ONE_MORE_VALUE');
ALTER TYPE ONE_MORE_ENUM OWNER TO postgres;
```

---

I have boield everything down that you should be able to test this yourself wihtout a lot of effort. With this setup i get the error described above.

Sql:

```
CREATE TYPE GRABART_MULTIPLIKATOR AS ENUM ('NICHT_MULTIPLIZIEREN', 'ANZAHL_GRABSTELLEN', 'FLAECHE');
ALTER TYPE GRABART_MULTIPLIKATOR OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE TABLE grab_art (
    id                                          SERIAL                 NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT grabart_pkey
            PRIMARY KEY,
    bezeichnung                                 TEXT,
    multiplikator                               GRABART_MULTIPLIKATOR
);

ALTER TABLE grab_art
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

C#:

```
class Program
{
    const string CONNECTION_STRING = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=my_db;search path=my_demo;User ID=postgres;Password=pw;";

    public enum Grabart_Multiplikator
    {
        [PgName("NICHT_MULTIPLIZIEREN")]
        NICHT_MULTIPLIZIEREN,
        [PgName("ANZAHL_GRABSTELLEN")]
        ANZAHL_GRABSTELLEN,
        [PgName("FLAECHE")]
        FLAECHE
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<Grabart_Multiplikator>("grabart_multiplikator");

            using (var connection = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
            {
                connection.Open();

                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO GRAB_ART (BEZEICHNUNG, MULTIPLIKATOR) VALUES (@BEZEICHNUNG, @MULTIPLIKATOR) RETURNING ID";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BEZEICHNUNG", "Neuer Rechtsträger");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("MULTIPLIKATOR", Grabart_Multiplikator.FLAECHE);
                var grabart_id = command.ExecuteScalar();

                command.Parameters.Clear();


                Console.WriteLine($"Success...");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }


}
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Enums have integer values.  So you can cast the Enums to integers.  In some cases the Enumber may not be integers but int16 or bytes.  So you have to define the Enums to the same values (and size) npsql expects.  So in some cases you may have to assign the enum to a value like SOME_VALUE = 0x10.  You do not have to register the Enum, just make sure you cast to correct size values.

Comment: In my case the enums are declared as strings in postgres. Everyone of them and most of them are still working... I will add the code which creates the enums in postgre to the question

Comment: Okay, but the documentation says, that you have to register the enums to use them. Since they are string, and enums in c# are not capable of having string as its underlying type, how am i going to do this?

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't give me any problems. My guess is that there is something different about your 3rd enum (that you have not shown) which is why it's not working. BTW the Npgsql connector maps C# enum types (int) to Postgres enum types (string).

Comment: @IanKemp thank you for your reply. I will take a closer look at the enums and declaration again. What do you mean by your last sentence? Is the way I map my enums not correct? Or is there another way to map it?

Comment: I have double checked everything and can not find any difference. I have boiled everything down to a minimal reproduceable example (check answere). I get this error using the code and db described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had this problem. Two enums with the same name in different Schemas.

Just set "schema.enum" in your entity configuration:

```
connection.TypeMapper.MapEnum<One_More_Enum>("schema.one_more_enum");
```

It works for me!

Comment: This came in handy, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a good solution to this, but I have found what is causing the problem and how to bypass this.

When I have two identical schemas on my database this problem occurs. Npgsql seems to be confuse from which schema it should take the enum and chooses the wrong one. (Like im doing an insert on schema_a and the enum is used from schema_b) I have tried to use `set search_path`, but this doesn't seem to help.

For now I only ever have one (of the same) schema on my database to make things work. Maybe someone with more experience in npgsl know how to solve this problem.

The problem seems to be that npgsql is confused about which enum it should use.